# How can i achieve the accurate and same lat long even when i revisit the same place

Tags: iphone, ios7, cllocationmanager

I want this functionality to achieve, that when the user repeats the visit to same place suppose a person moves one meter forward then one meter back. He should get the same lat long value what he gets his previous time. I mean to accuracy for every footstep the user takes with device. How can i achieve this. Currently i am using CLLocationManager but it is giving the difference of 20 to 30 points at last in lat long when i moves at same place again.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1f;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

NSDate *locationTimeStamp = newLocation.timestamp;

NSTimeInterval delta = [locationTimeStamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

NSLog(@"The location timestamp interval was %f seconds.", delta);


_latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
_longitude.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
_time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",delta];
}
```

Comment: What does "points" refer to: degrees? It's not clear what level of accuracy you're expecting. Also, what horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy values are you getting?

Comment: @LarsH updated the question please check.

Comment: It's out of your control. Lots of factors need to be taken into consideration, GPS signal, battery level, environmental constraints, etc. This is why desired accuracy level is in the APIs, you have to compromise.

Comment: Thanks for showing the code. What does "points" refer to: degrees? Also, what horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy values are you getting?

Comment: @LarsH I am trying to clear my question again. What i need is that suppose a user standing in front of the shop he should get notification and when he enters the shop he get another notification. Yesterday i came to know about using radius and region to use for this purpose. But i don't have any idea about how to use it.